# Finding a formula for $\sum^n_{k=0}h_k$

Tags: combinatorics, sequences-and-series

Let the sequence $\{ h_n\}_{n\geq}$ be defined by $h_n=2n^2-n+3$.  Determine the difference table, and find a formula for $$\sum^n_{k=0}h_k$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n} h_k = \sum_{k=0}^{n} \left(2k^2 - k +3\right) = 2 \left(\sum_{k=0}^n k^2 \right) - \left(\sum_{k=0}^n k \right) + 3 \left(\sum_{k=0}^n 1 \right)$$
Now make use of the following:
$$\sum_{k=0}^n 1 = n$$
$$\sum_{k=0}^n k = \dfrac{n(n+1)}2$$
$$\sum_{k=0}^n k^2 = \dfrac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}6$$